# 404 error for pages that working fine on google search console

Tags: google-search-console, 404

I have a website that has over 2 million pages, for some time now I am seeing on google search console 404 errors for pages that are working fine and that I know for a fact were working fine before we received the indication regarding those errors, does anybody have any idea what could be the reason, if it ever happened to anyone before I'll be more than happy to hear what was the solution you came up with

Comment: Have you checked the last crawl date? You may be seeing errors it found long ago that have since been fixed. You can mark everything as fixed for now and see whether or not they pop up again within a month or two as a way to determine whether they are still real errors or something from long ago.

Comment: i allready tried that i see the error on the same date and is never detectet few months ago they are always fresh, something like this: first detected 04.23.2018 last crawled 23.04.2018